# Docker devicemapper storage space

Tags: linux, docker, containers, device-mapper

Am getting the "no space left on device" error while removing a container.

```
# docker rm orientdb1
Error response from daemon: Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem ba18ea8014b6024eb738502612130244ff363b433f146102c64eb2eb0f3a321c: devmapper: Error saving transaction metadata: devmapper: Error creating metadata file: open /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/metadata/.tmp636968871: no space left on device
```

Here is a snippet from "df -kh" output.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  3.8T  3.8T   20K 100% /
```

Here is a snippet from "du -ksh " output. Which shows that 3.8TB is used.

```
3.8T    /var/lib/docker
```

This is the "docker info" output.

```
# docker info
Containers: 56
 Running: 8
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 48
Images: 18
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-1196768-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 24.51 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 20.48 kB
 Metadata Space Used: 29.18 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 20.48 kB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for 
 production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom 
 block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
  Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2016-06-09)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host overlay null
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 12
Total Memory: 251.7 GiB
Name: my-host1
ID: KTTY:PSTQ:YQSP:9KZJ:VSVU:DFUZ:CEMF:DYWQ:CA3I:6KUB:6J2J:D4NG
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Would like to understand how 3.8 TB is accounted for from the following (snippet from "docker info")

```
 Data Space Used: 24.51 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 20.48 kB
 Metadata Space Used: 29.18 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 20.48 kB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
```

Also how can I clean /var/lib/docker to get some free space.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the disk space figures are for the loopback driver and the file /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data that is used by devicemapper in the loopback mode.

To cleanup the docker, you can run `docker system prune` on a newer release. Older releases can use commands like:

```
docker ps -aqf status=exited | xargs docker rm
docker images -qf dangling=true | xargs docker rmi
```

Beyond that, you will need to go through containers and images to `docker stop`, `docker rm` on the container, and `docker rmi` on the image.

Answer (score 0):

To add to BMitch's answer, you can also remove dangling volumes to free up space using something like `docker volume ls -f dangling=true | xargs docker volume rm`